# Not able to increase height of uiview using it's subview height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, subview

I am using autolayout for set height of uiview depends on it's subview.
I am using Reusable view.

I have added that view in my viewcontroller is here is code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSArray *arrNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReUsableView" owner:self options:nil];

UIView *subView = [arrNib objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:subView];
lbl1 = [subView viewWithTag:1];
lbl1.text = @"fjadsk jkdjf kasdjf kasjdfkas djfkjads kfjaksd fjaskdjf kdsajf ksdjf ksdaj fksadjfkadsjf ksadjfksajd fkdsjfkajf kcnvmjkdalsjfk vaksdjfkj kfdvnkdsjfkajfkda djfkajsdfksja dfksjdafkjas;fjsk";


}
```

I got output like this

[image]

When I will remove bottom constaint of lbl first then I got following output.

[image]

How can I increase the height of uiview depends on lbl first height?

Appreciate for help!

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to increase the size of your blue view with lbl, You have to do following things

- Give the fixed height constraints to the  lbl1.
- Remove height constraint to container view.
- Add equal height constraints to container view & lbl1
- Change the multiplier property of equal widths constraints by
  calculating containerView height / lbl1 height  ("/" means divide by)
- Take outlet of height constraints of lbl1.
- Calculate the changed height of lbl1.Assign this to height
  constraints of lbl by setting constraints.constant property.

Answer (score 0):

to make this happen, required constraints for view is;

```
top=view.top
leading = view.leading
trailing = view.trailing
bottom >= view.bottom
```

lhs of equations belongs to superview of your view.
for label inside;

```
lbl.top = view.top
lbl.leading = view.leading
lbl.trailing = view.trailing
lbl.bottom = view.bottom.
```

i built it in storyboard; here is the screenshot. view size is getting bigger when the text inside the label is getting longer.

[image]